# Normalize row and column sums of a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices

This is a slightly stupid question, and I am quite embarrassed that I cannot answer it.

Let $A = (a_{ij})_{ij}$ be a a symmetric matrix. Is it always possible to find a matrix $S$ such that for $A' = (a'_{ij}))_{ij} = SAS^T$ such that the row and column sums satisfy

$$\sum_{i} a'_{ij} = \sum_{i} a'_{ji} = 1$$

for all $j$? If not, is there a conditition under which this becomes possible?

Comment: Also, you could start by considering the simpler case where $\bf S$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
$Your question is related to the [Sinkhorn Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinkhorn%27s_theorem) which says that diagonal matrices $(D_1,D_2)$ exists such that $D_1AD_2$ is doubly stochastic.

It is not necessary that $D_1=D_2$ even if $A$ is symmetric.

For example
$$\eqalign{
A &= \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0.42 & 0.14 & 0.20 \\
0.14 & 0.24 & 0.41 \\
0.20 & 0.41 & 0.20 \\\end{array}
\right],
\qquad
D_1AD_2 = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0.5631 & 0.1837 & 0.2531 \\
0.1837 & 0.3083 & 0.5079 \\
0.2531 & 0.5079 & 0.2389 \\\end{array}
\right] \\
\\
D_1 &= {\rm Diag}\big(1.30561,\quad 1.27800,\quad 1.232420\big) \\
D_2 &= {\rm Diag}\big(1.02695,\quad 1.00523,\quad 0.969383\big) \\
}$$
which was calculated using a standard
*Iterative Proportional Fitting* algorithm.

The desired form $(SAS^T)$ can be obtained by setting
$$\eqalign{
S &= \sqrt{D_1D_2} \\
  &= {\rm Diag}\big(1.15793,\quad 1.13344,\quad 1.09302\big) \\
}$$

Comment: why do you assume $A$ has no negative entries?  Assuming $A\in \mathbb R^n$, it seems to me the answer to OP's question is *yes if and only if A is not negative semi-definite*.